# Company page ads goes to undefined

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

The company page ads:

[image]

Are clickable and go to some strange url, namely:

http://undefined/ct?at=1&tz=4&ti=0&utm=%26utm_source%3Dcareers.stackoverflow.com%26utm_medium%3Dad%26utm_campaign%3Dundefined

Please make these images not clickable.

Comment: Did you observe this problem with a company page ad running on Stack Overflow? It appears that you're referring to a preview page on Careers, which is for employers interested in publishing company page ads.

Comment: @Max - exactly, my role serves both - I use careers as an employer but I also use jobs as a candidate.  In this case, I am using it as an employer.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see the problem now. Stand by...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the report! This looks to have been fixed a while back, marking it as status-completed!